# LinkButton OnClick event does not fire in Bootstrap drop-down menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I am developing an ASP.Net application. I have implemented a Bootstrap Navbar. Everything is working as expected except when I try to implement an `<asp:LinkButton>` inside on of the `dropdown-menu`'s.

Here's a snippet:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="btnLogout" runat="server" OnClick="btnLogout_Click">
            Log out
        </asp:LinkButton>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Basically this Log out `LinkButton` is a drop-down menu item. When I run the application and click it, all it does is toggle the drop-down menu to close again.

I've set a break point in the `btnLogout_Click` event but it never gets reached which indicates the event is never fired.

Is there anyway to make this `LinkButton`'s OnClick event fire properly?

**Note:** It works if I double click (i.e. click it again before it fully closes). But this is not ideal for the UX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
<li>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="btnLogout" runat="server" OnClick="btnLogout_Click">
        Log out
    </asp:LinkButton>
</li>
```

Try this

Comment: Wow, I can't believe it was such a simple fix, thank you!